# message: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (SQL: select * from `users`...)"

Tags: angular, laravel

I developed a Web Portal on Windows Operating System using Angular-7 as the frontend and Laravel-5.8 as the backend. Before deployment, I tested everything on the local machine and it was okay.

The Linux Ubuntu server IP is: 20.10.10.122
The Laravel file path is:

http://120.10.10.122/client-app/backend

.env

```
APP_NAME=Client
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:QT/LLNA/aduSekOXF4/CsY1iYEcRwwwwssssssHxuFs=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=http://localhost/
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=client
DB_USERNAME=jdggsss
DB_PASSWORD=kjhgfdddd
```

However, when I deployed to Linux Ubuntu-18 Server, I ran the application. When the user tried to login, I got this error:

> message: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = noblemfd@yahoo.com and `active` = 1 and `deleted_at` is null and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)"

Why am I getting the error and how do I resolve it?

Comment: I think Laravel is trying to connect to a remote database server and failing to do so, post your `.env` `DB_HOST`

Comment: @Saly3301 - I have added the .env

Comment: Change your `DB_HOST` to `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change your environment variable to connect to the local MySQL server via TCP

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=client
DB_USERNAME=jdggsss
DB_PASSWORD=kjhgfdddd
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `DB_HOST` environment variable is clearly wrong. You added the `http://` [URI Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes) to it. The `http://` scheme is for identifying a http protocol, MySQL don't use it.

You should use only the `hostname`, without prefixes:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```